# Getting Started tutorial for GAE on Python is not running

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Trying to run the helloworld app from the Getting Started on GAE and it gives me a blank page.

I have the file `hell2/hell2.py`:

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
  self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
  self.response.write('Hello, webapp2 World!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],
                          debug=True)
```

and the file `app.yaml` in same dir:

```
application: hell2
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: hell2.py
```

the tutorial on the google page says script should have .app extension but that throws an error right away. also using python27 as the runtime cannot find python, which is python 2.7.3 btw. as is it runs but the browser does not show the text.
the older example based on webapp works fine. I checked and found webapp2.py is in the SDK.

Comment: if you have got your answer pls mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

in the runtime tag goes python27 instead python

you need change

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: hell2.app
```

Comment: Correct. And to be clear on what's going on here, '.app' isn't an extension; it's a path to a WSGIApplication. If the variable 'application' has been used instead, it'd be `hell2.application`.

Comment: amazing. yesterday it wouldn't, now it runs with python27 and using .app

Answer (score 0):

`.app` is not the extension -- rather, it is a variable in the Python module `hell2`. So, change the line in app.yaml to this:

```
script: hell2.app
```